# trying to set the logging for REALM / Tomcat and Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellij 11 and trying to debug REALM and LDAP

i found this article 
[Configure debug logging for Realms and Authentication](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2010/03/enable-debugtrace-level-logging-for.html)

the problem is that i am modifying the CATALINA_HOME/conf/logging.properties and 
intellij seems to be ignoring it.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: IDEA will use a copy of this file under [idea.system.path](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108)`\tomcat\<RUN CONFIG NAME>\conf\logging.properties`. Check that it's modified as well.

Comment: hello, thanks
when i start the webapp, i can open the logging.properties in system.path location and it has the correct settings (as mentioned in the article) but no REALM debug output at all

Comment: Does it work outside of IDEA if you start Tomcat normally and deploy your app manually?

Comment: yes, if i deploy locally in tomcat it works, just does not work in intellij

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in Tomcat integration. I've created an [issue in YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108221), please vote.